# Custom Timezones in Android

Tags: date-and-time, time-zones

Is it possible to set the timezone of an android device (either a physical device or and emulator) to a timezone that doesn't actually exist (for instance, GMT+00:03 or GMT-500:00)?  I tried reading the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/icu/util/TimeZone), and it seems like the data type supports that in theory, but I have no idea how you'd actually do that in practice, or if there's some reason it's impossible that I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not without using/creating a Custom ROM**

So the link you provided is for Android app developers who need to create custom timezone for their usage within Android Apps. Other apps wouldn't be affected by any internal time/date calculation or settings done in that manner.

You can set an emulator's timezone on startup:

[Android Emulator command line options](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html)

> **-timezone *timezone***
>
> Set the timezone for the virtual device to timezone, instead of the host timezone
> By default, the emulator uses the timezone of your development computer. Use this option to specify a different timezone or if the automatic detection isn't working correctly. The timezone value must be in zoneinfo format, which is area/location or area/subarea/location. For example:
>
> - America/Los_Angeles
> - Europe/Paris
> - America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires
>
> **The specified timezone must be in the zoneinfo database.**

But you are limited to the existing timezone in the zoneinfo database (also known as `tzdata`).

[Date/Time/Timezone rules are complicated](https://youtu.be/-5wpm-gesOY) so the Android Open Source Project has a section on [Time Zone Updates](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/timezone-rules).

What this means is that the complexity of time zone management is 'centralized' into `tzdata` and `tzlookup.xml` files. As `tzdata` database is used by many other systems and maintained by the [Internet Assigned Numbers Authority organization](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), the mechanism by which you can modify the file is off-topic as it is not Android specific.